# Extract date from filename

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have files named in the format gtYYMMDD.txt like for example gt130422.txt, I'd like to extract the date from this file name in the format 2013/04/22.

I'd like to precise that my script, when I execute it, it asks only for the date:

```
filetoread = "/home/scripts/gt"
raw_input("Enter date, please. For example, 130415: ") + ".txt"
```

So the date I want to get is a function of what the user types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> filetoread = "/home/scripts/gt/"
>>> s = raw_input("Enter date please e.g: 130415: ")
Enter date please e.g: 130415: 130422
>>> date = datetime.strptime(s, '%y%m%d')
>>> print date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
2013/04/22
>>> path = filetoread + s + ".txt"
```

Comment: It looks to me like the OP should not append `.txt` at the `raw_input` stage - do as you show above (minus the `splitext`), then append `.txt` after...

Comment: @JonClements ok thanks, I wasn't really sure what OP was asking for

Comment: thanks but that's not exactly what i want, actually i want it to return for example 2013/04/15

Comment: @SkivlageLatif did you see my update

Comment: On a side note - `print format(date, '%Y/%m/%d')` is quite cool ;)

Comment: I just did =) thanks !!